# JS - add ParseInt value to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json

Working with bad data from backend, I need to convert strings to integers.

I have JSON:

```
{
    "cars": [
        "36",
        "49",
        "73"
    ]
}
```

I have an attempt to convert the strings to integers.

```
let cars= res.data.products[0].cars;
                for (const key of Object.keys(cars)) {
                    setSelectedCars(selCars=> [...selCars, parseInt(cars, 0)]);
                }
```

This attempt does not work as I loop it wrong and end with single value being present multiple times in array while "" remains.

The desired outcome would thus be:

```
{
    "cars": [
        36,
        49,
        73
    ]
}
```

Comment: `xxx.cars.forEach((v, i, a) => a[i] = +v)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `map` and convert each to a `number`.

```js
const data = {
    "cars": [
        "36",
        "49",
        "73"
    ]
}

data.cars = data.cars.map(Number);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Wonderful solution. Thank you!